# Push Operation in TortoiseHg

Tags: tortoisehg

I have committed 6 change sets and now i want to push them to server. Can I do it just by using Push outgoing changes button? or should I update these change sets then push one by one.

Because I have no local changes now. If I push, then from where my change sets will move to server? From my local or some other repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I do it just by using Push outgoing changes button?

Yes

> If I push, then from where my change sets will move to server?

Welll, try to read docs? From local repository.

With Mercurial, you interact with 3 entities:

- Working directory (you have real physical files in it and changes made here)
- Local repository: `.hg` subdir in Working directory (you commit changes from WD into it)
- Remote repository, other side for pull|push operations, there "my" is **local repository**

On pull|push trees of remote and local repository have to be compared and missing changesets copied and needed direction